# How to create a python plugin?

Tags: python, plugins

The following is the example I would like to do

I have different vehicle for Two-Door car, Bus, Van but they are the inherited from 'Vehicle'. What I want to do is to create a base class ('Vehicle') so everyone need to follow. And then people can build their own plugins (e.g. Bus, Van).

Then other users would use the plugin like this

```
my_vehicle = Vehicle('bus')
```

Then the bus class will be used.

I got the idea but I have no idea how should it be implemented?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a metaclass for this:

```
class VehicleType(type):
    registry = {}

    def __init__(self, name, bases, attrs):
        self.registry[name.lower()] = self

    def __call__(self, name):
        cls = self.registry[name]
        inst = cls.__new__(cls)
        inst.__init__()
        return inst


class Vehicle(object):
    __metaclass__ = VehicleType


class Car(Vehicle):
    pass


car = Vehicle("car")
print(type(car))  # <class '__main__.Car'>
```

This works by having the class inheritance process register the class in the metaclass, then overriding the behavior of calling `Vehicle` so that it dynamically dispatches to the appropriate class.

Comment: Thanks I think I need a metaclass. Let me study more on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use an already existing plugin library such as [stevedore](http://stevedore.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

This gives you:

- A concise way to create plugins
- Several ways to dynamically load them